# Drawing webgl primitives

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I know how to draw squares, rectangles and triangles with WebGL. however, i'm a bit confused on how to draw a circle using triangle_fan. I created an array containing vertices and binded it to a buffer.

In the way that I draw triangles etc, i create an array to fill up its vertices.

`var circle= [...];`

So when i do that to create a circle, it seems that i have to put a lot of vertices to make it smooth.

Is there a way to create a circle with simpler and less code?

Comment: Did you use loop to fill vertex array? I think it takes about 5 lines of code.

Comment: @Unick how do you fill it using a loop?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is set the first two vertices in the list to be `(0,0,0)` and `(1,0,0)`. Then you can calculate the remaining vertices using `cos()` and `sin()`, because those will return the x and y values of points on a circle.

```
var numTris = 100;

vertices = [
     0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
     1.0,  0.0,  0.0
];

var degPerTri = (2 * Math.PI) / numTris;

for(var i = 0; i < numTris; i++) {
    var index = 2*3 + i*3
    var angle = degPerTri * (i+1);

    vertices[index] = Math.cos(angle); 
    vertices[index+1] = Math.sin(angle); 
    vertices[index+2] = 0; 
}
```

Here is an image that shows you what order `TRIANGLE_FAN` expects the vertices to be in:
[image]

The very first vertex in the list will be shared by every triangle in the fan (so it will be the center of our circle). And each triangle in the fan is composed of two consecutive vertices along with the first vertex in the list. Note that vertex 1 and 7 are at the same position.

You can see it in action here:

```js
var gl;
function initGL(canvas) {
    try {
        gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
        gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
        gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
    } catch (e) {
    }
    if (!gl) {
        alert("Could not initialise WebGL, sorry :-(");
    }
}


function getShader(gl, id) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!shaderScript) {
        return null;
    }

    var str = "";
    var k = shaderScript.firstChild;
    while (k) {
        if (k.nodeType == 3) {
            str += k.textContent;
        }
        k = k.nextSibling;
    }

    var shader;
    if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    } else if (shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
        shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    gl.shaderSource(shader, str);
    gl.compileShader(shader);

    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}


var shaderProgram;

function initShaders() {
    var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
    var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

    shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert("Could not initialise shaders");
    }

    gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

    shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

    shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
    shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
}


var mvMatrix = mat4.create();
var pMatrix = mat4.create();

function setMatrixUniforms() {
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform, false, pMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform, false, mvMatrix);
}



var squareVertexPositionBuffer;

function initBuffers() {
    squareVertexPositionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);

    var numTris = 100;

    vertices = [
         0.0,  0.0,  0.0,
         1.0,  0.0,  0.0
    ];

    var degPerTri = (2 * Math.PI) / numTris;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < numTris; i++) {
        var index = 2*3 + i*3
        var angle = degPerTri * (i+1);

        vertices[index] = Math.cos(angle); 
        vertices[index+1] = Math.sin(angle); 
        vertices[index+2] = 0; 
    }

    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = numTris + 2;
}


function drawScene() {
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight, 0.1, 100.0, pMatrix);

    mat4.identity(mvMatrix);

    mat4.translate(mvMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -3.0]);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, squareVertexPositionBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, squareVertexPositionBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    setMatrixUniforms();
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, squareVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
}



function webGLStart() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    initGL(canvas);
    initShaders();
    initBuffers();

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    drawScene();
}
```

```html
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://antonpantev.com/so-related/attribsnotsetup/custom_lesson4_files/glMatrix-0.9.5.min.js"></script><style type="text/css">.cf-hidden { display: none; } .cf-invisible { visibility: hidden; }</style>

<script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    void main(void) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
</script>

<script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
    attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

    uniform mat4 uMVMatrix;
    uniform mat4 uPMatrix;

    void main(void) {
        gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="webGLStart();">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border: none;" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the loop that will fill up the circle! It was just what I needed. I thought when you create an array it would be fixed in size but then you can still add vertices in it. I really learned a lot.

Comment: I would like to ask a question. How do you create a circle where the circle can be placed at a specific point in the canvas. Because when I tested you code, I can change the size of the circle but it won't let me place the circle at a specifice point. I would like to know how to move the circle because changing the center point won't do the job.

Comment: If you look at the full example code in the `drawScene()` function, you will see a matrix called `mvMatrix`. You can move (translate), rotate, and scale that one matrix and if you do so the circle will change along with it. If that doesn't make enough sense to you then you should check out the following tutorial to get a better fuller explanation. http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28

Comment: so it's in the drawscene but is it possible to just modify the code for the circle instead of going through the drawscene in the snippet?

Comment: It is possible but its more work. You have to loop through each vertex in the array and add the position of the center point to each vertex in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the common approach is to use a lot of vertices to make not perfect circle/ball. Since we use pixels to display things, circles/balls are never perfect, but might look like as a perfect one.

For example in [three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/) basic circle is done from 32 triangles. You should increase or decrease the amount based on how far will camera be from circle.

Anyway there are another ways how to create perfect shapes, not just circle. Case by case, your imagination or pattern is used to achieve it.

For example in webgl we have points and triangles only. It is possible to modify final look in shader:

- Before draw, you establish set of points/triangles you want to draw.
- Then vertex shader turns. It might modify position of each vertex. It is probably not helpful now, so I will skip description now.
- Fragment shader turns. Fragment shader says what color should be displayed on the position of each pixel that is covered by triangle/point.
  Now the important part is, you can use aplha channel to render transparent color (or advanced you can skip drawing this pixel - not sure about this). So what you can do is inscribed circle. If you change the position of vertices with vertex shader, you can also do circumscribed circle. [Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/windkiller/7wx6zoe2/8/), it is from previously answered question [Change color in middle of circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966841/change-color-in-middle-of-circle/26044181#26044181)

Core part from fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 pos;

uniform vec2 middle;
uniform float r;

void main() {
    // inscribed circle math
    if (distance(pos.xy, middle) > r) {
        discard;
    }
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

I wouldn't say this is the best option, it is just possible.

Widely used are for example [Bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) which might help you to achieve any custom shape. This is usually not used in real time rendering being too slow, but good for prerendered videos or movies.

Last thing I should mention are vertex normals. This is core thing. You assign each vertex a normal vector. Then you can use this vector in shaders to modify light reflection or more. Then ball looks like better because there are no sharp edges in reflection. 
Watch [this demo](http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/reactive-ball/) as example. If you play with it for a while, you will recognize quite large triangles on the surface, or you can notice that if you focus on the edge. But if you dont focus, ball seems perfect. It is because of the mirror which distracts your attention. One colored ball wouldnt look like this.
Normals can be also used same as bezier curves.

Comment: thanks. i've already learned about vertex and fragment shader. like what @Unick said, how can i fill up my array using loop if it's possible that would turn into a circle when i execute `gl.drawArray(triangle_fan)`